# PubNub connections per channel

Tags: objective-c, events, pubnub

Does subscribing to multiple PubNub channels share an HTTP connection or create separate connections?

The reason for asking is that clients will receive notifications from a central hub.

- We can use channels for routing the notification types. (Like REST).
- We can have a single channel for events, with an `event_type` field. (Like SOAP).

The former is preferable in terms of implementation simplicity, so just checking if there are any drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Connections Per Channel

PubNub SDK client connections utilize one TCP connection per SDK instance.  The number of channels used will not increase the open TCP connection count.  *Multiple PubNub channels share a connection.* PubNub uses **Multiplexing** allowing your channel messages to be received using only one TCP connection.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub now offers Channel Groups and Wildcard Subscribe via the Stream Controller add-on

### Channel Groups

PubNub now offers Channel Groups so that one client connection can subscribe to 20K channels at once (10 channel groups X 2000 channels in each channel group). [See Channel Groups KBs](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channel-groups) for more details.

### Wildcard Subscribe

Subscribe to `a.b.*` and publish to any channel that is prefixed by `a.b.` (a.b.c, a.b.d, a.b.aa, etc) and your `a.b.*` subscribe will get those messages. [See Wildcard KBs](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/wildcard-subscribe) for more details.